# Is my laptop SSD possibly corrupt?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, crash, bsod

During the last few days Windows 10 Pro (64 bit) on my Medion laptop has been constantly crashing, mostly at random times. So there are times I can't even use my laptop for more than 2 minutes before it crashes, sometimes I can use it for 3 hours straight.

What I tried:

- Reinstalled all drivers from manufacturers
- Uninstalled all drivers, and installed drivers from OEM
- Running memtest86+ (which at times reported no errors, or some errors)
- Running sfc /scannow (which reported corrupted files found, but couldn't fix them)
- Running dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth (Windows crashed at 20% - every time)
- Refreshed Windows (crashed at 1%)
- "Repair drive for errors" utility (took 10 hours to finish, crashed after it finished)

Why I think it's a hard drive issue:

- Windows crashes every time I try to fix/read files from C:\Windows
- sfc reports corrupted files
- The BSODs that I get mainly list NTFS.sys as cause

This may be helpful:

- Windows is installed on a 128gb SSD from Samsung
- I installed Ubuntu on a partition on that drive a few months ago, but decided to remove it due to driver problems
- I have Windows 10 Pro Build 10586.29 64 bit, with the latest updates installed
- My laptop came with Windows 8
- The BSODs I get have a random error message, but mostly I get "IRLQ_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL", "PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA" and "SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION". According to Blue Screen View, the main drivers that cause this are: ntoskrnl.exe, NTFS.sys, dxgkrnl.sys, igdkmd64.sys

Can the cause be a faulty hard drive that I can possibly fix (or a professional), or is the drive hopelessly corrupted?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Have you tried formatting the SSD and reinstalling Windows? It may be a corrupted MBR/GPT or file system. If this does not help, I suspect the drive has been physically damaged and needs to be replaced. You may try to save all the important files using a Live OS.

Comment: You have obviously corrupted files. So what do you expect. Suggest you reinstall everything.

Comment: You have faulty RAM. I'd have thought the fact that Memtest reported "some errors" would have made that clear.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq not always, as far as I know it can report false positives, but I might be wrong. I'll look into it thx!

Comment: No it does not report false positives. You have errors that are symptomatic of a RAM problem. You've done a RAM test that reports a RAM problem. What else do you need before you believe it's a RAM problem? You might have an SSD issue that's exacerbating it but you still have to deal with the RAM issue first. Bad RAM is one of the worst failures you can have as it can silently corrupt everything without you knowing.

Comment: So I tried to clean install Windows, but it crashed and now it is stuck in a weird loop with a black screen. Force shutting it down also doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Replace. Your. RAM.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq ok, so I guess I was wrong. I'll send my laptop to repair. Thanks guys

Comment: I agree with @qasdfdsaq, it sounds like a ram problem. They can be the most annoying of problems to live with and to diagnose. But his initial response about the ram immedately resonated with me. Then again, now you know its not a corrupted file, which makes it easier to pinpoint. There still could potentially be a problem with your SSD, and if you have a spare hard drive laying around you might want to test that first because it wont cost you any money to do so. Replacing the ram means you have to spend money, and if that's a hardship for you, rule out as many things as possible before $$$